# Is there a location for custom Ruby libraries to be stored so Ruby can find them?

Tags: ruby, macos, filesystems

I have written a module that has some generic, reusable code that I would like to be able to use in other projects. Is there a place I could put this file on computer so that Ruby can find it regardless of where I saved the file that is including it? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard place to put code like this.  You could put all your code in a gem and install the gem, or create a directory to put this code in.  Once you create the directory, alter the LOAD_PATH global variable to include this directory.  You can do this either in each script that uses these, or with the RUBYOPT environment variable.  For example, you could put ~/my_ruby_stuff in your path and put your files there.  One warning if you do that, make sure the path you add is at the *end* of the gem path and try to avoid any name conflicts with existing Ruby libraries or gems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a "gem" out of your code. The advantages are: separate project, better defined interface, separate source control, can share with other developers in your company, etc